# Snapshot.value crashed on setValueForKeys

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
func observeMessages(){
  let ref = Database.database().reference().child("messages")
  ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
      if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
          let message = Message()
          print(dictionary)
          message.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
          self.messages.append(message)
          DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableView.reloadData() }
      }
  }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

This is part of my Firebase&swift project. I keep crashing every time I try to call the message.setValuesForKeys(dictionary).

The error message from the console is

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key toId

I checked the dictionary and it has the data as I want. I don't know what else I can check. I tried to change the "snapshot.value" to "snapshot.children.allobjects" but with that change I cannot access to the data inside my dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is one of your firebase nodes has a key that doesn't exist in your class

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key toId

```
                                                                      ^^^^
```

This is a good clue.

Check through the nodes in your firebase and ensure they all have a key toId and that your class also has a toId property.

Mismatching keys will cause this issue.

Also, if you want to use setObjectForValue, the Message object should inherit from NSObject (which is key-value coding compliant)

> Objects typically adopt key-value coding when they inherit from
>   NSObject (directly or indirectly), which both adopts the
>   NSKeyValueCoding protocol and provides a default implementation for
>   the essential methods

If you've checked to ensure your keys all match up then it could be how the Message object is defined. It should look something like this, ensuring it's an NSObject and the keys (properties) start with *@objc*

```
class Message: NSObject {
    @objc var name = ""
    @objc var toId = ""
}
```

My last suggestion is make your code Swifty and don't rely on NSObject.

```
class Message {
  var name = ""
  var toId = ""
  func initMessageWithSnap(aSnapshot: Snapshot) {
      //desconstuct the snapshot and assign the vars
  }
}
```